# Sqlite.Swift: Counting number of rows whose column/field value is "x"

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I've been working with Sqlite.Swift for quite a while now and I'm stuck.
I'm trying to get an `Int` out of the `.count` of only the amount of rows containing the `String` value "1" in the column "yes or no".

I've been using the following function to randomly pick a row only once (without repeating). I thought this must be a good start to define the `.count` for only the described rows but I have absolutely no clue if this'd be possible.

This is how I got my "row randomizer" working:

```
func randomNumber() -> Int {

   var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(try! database.scalar(table.select(ItemId.distinct.count)))))

   while pickedNumber == randomNumber {

          randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(try! database.scalar(table.select(ItemId.distinct.count)))))

     }

      pickedNumber = randomNumber

      return randomNumber

  }

let randomRow = randomNumber()
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question:

Simply this did the job:

```
let count = try! database.scalar(tableName.where(expression == "1").count)
```

Edit:

You can see the `!` here. I did this because I'm *sure* there is a table where there's a column of that name with cells containing a `String` value of 1. If you want to go a more secure way use the `do` / `try` / `catch` mechanic.